# How to load a remote js file?

Tags: javascript, casperjs

test.js file (ex : http://domain.com/test.js)

```
var myjs = function()
{
     this.getName = function(){
         return 'this is a name';
     }
}
```

casperjs run.js (windows 7)

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
    loadImages: false,
    logLevel:   "error", //debug
    verbose:    true
});

casper.then(function() { // <-- no more run() but then()
    phantom.injectJs('http://domain.com/test.js');
    var my_ = new myjs(casper);
        name = my_.getName();
        this.echo(name);
});
```

I know, phantom.injectJs does not support `http://`, but must be used through the website.

I do not know what to do.

Comment: Please make it clear. Do you want to inject the script into the page context (inside `casper.evaluate`) or do you want to use it in casper context (outside `casper.evaluate`)? If you don't know, what I mean, please read the [documentation](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate) or my description [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24219029/1816580).

Comment: I want to load website js function..
um.. like dynamic function?
Read your link, but do not understand.
use evaluate instead of injectJs?

plz, sample code or Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you mean, because you (incorrectly) try to use `injectJS` which is for page context, but then pass a casper instance into `myjs`. So I provide 3 solutions.

## Load into casper through require

If you want to load a remote file just as you would use `require` to load a local file into casper, then you should [`download`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#download) it first:

```
var myjs;
casper.start(url)
casper.then(function(){
    this.download('http://domain.com/test.js', 'test.js');
    myjs = require('test'); // require the downloaded file
});
casper.then(function(){
    // do your thing
    var my_ = new myjs(casper);
    name = my_.getName();
    this.echo(name);
});
```

Doing that means that you have to export the function in the test.js file:

```
module.export = function(casper) {
    this.getName = function(){
        return 'this is a name';
    };
};
```

If the test.js is located on another domain, then you need to start casperjs with `--web-security=false` flag.

## Load into casper through `eval`

If you don't want to change test.js into a module then you could [sent an ajax request](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/clientutils.html#sendajax) to get the script and simply `eval` it.

```
var globalmyjs;
casper.start(url)
casper.then(function(){
    var testJS = this.evaluate(function(){
        return __utils__.sendAJAX('http://domain.com/test.js', 'GET', null, false); // synchronous
    });
    eval(testJS);
    globalmyjs = myjs;
});
casper.then(function(){
    // do your thing
    var my_ = new globalmyjs(casper);
    name = my_.getName();
    this.echo(name);
});
```

If the test.js is located on another domain, then you need to start casperjs with `--web-security=false` flag.

## Load into page context

Use this if `myjs` is to be executed in page context.

If you want to use the underlying phantomjs then it provides the <kbd>[includeJs(url, callback)](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/include-js.html)</kbd> function.

So you can use it like this:

```
var scriptLoaded = false;
casper.then(function() {
    phantom.includeJs('http://domain.com/test.js', function(){
        scriptLoaded = true;
    });
    casper.waitFor(function check() {
        return scriptLoaded;
    }, function then() {
        this.evaluate(function(){
            var my_ = new myjs(casper);
            name = my_.getName();
            console.log(name);
        });
    });
});
```

Though, you should use the <kbd>[casper.options.remoteScripts](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#remotescripts)</kbd> property.

So either inject the script on creation:

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
    remoteScripts: [ 'http://domain.com/test.js' ]
});
```

or before a page load:

```
casper.options.remoteScripts.push('http://domain.com/test.js');
casper.start(url);
// or
casper.thenOpen(url);
```