# Message does not appear when called from evaluate method

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I'm new to casperjs and playing around with it, but I can't get its `evaluate()` functionality to work.

This is my example

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.echo('started...');

casper.start('http://www.google.de/');

casper.then(function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.then(function() {
    this.evaluate(function() {
        this.echo('test');
    });
});

casper.run();
```

I'm executing it with `casperjs sample.js`

After `started...` and `Google` nothing happens in console output. The closure function given in the evaluate method is not executed.

I don't even get further informations by console with `--verbose`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside of the [`casper.evaluate`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate) callback is the page context. Everything in it executes directly on the page and it is sandboxed. `this` refers to the `window` object inside this callback. I doubt that google has added a `window.echo` function. So you will not see something in the console. `this.echo` or `casper.echo` are only usable outside of the page context.

To actually see console messages from the page context you need to register to the [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) event:

```js
casper.on("remote.message", function(msg){
    this.echo("remote.msg: " + msg);
});
```

and write something to the console:

```js
this.evaluate(function() {
    console.log('test');
});
```

If you would have registered to the [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) event:

```js
casper.on("page.error", function(pageErr){
    this.echo("page.err: " + JSON.stringify(pageErr));
});
```

you would have seen, that `window.echo` cannot be called because it is `undefined`. Calling it, will result in a TypeError, which stops execution of the `evaluate()` callback, which then gives you `null` as the result of the `evaluate()` execution.

For more info on `evaluate` see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24219029/1816580).

*Note:* It is not a good idea to try to write your first scripts on google, because you will run into multiple problems. Google sniffs the user-agent and will give you a different site depending on it. Also the viewport size will be taken into account. I would suggest you start with example.org and then stackoverflow.com, because both behave rather well.