# casperjs evaluate not executing

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm new to casperjs,the evaluate function is not getting executed

```
casper.start('https://piedmont.taleo.net/careersection/2/moresearch.ftl?lang=en',function(){

    casper.page.injectJs('/Users/manoj/apply_robots/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js');
    this.echo(this.getTitle());

    this.wait(3000,processPage);
    this.echo("before processPage");

    });

    function processPage()
    {

        this.echo("inside processPage");
        var c = [];

        c = this.evaluate(getJ);
        this.echo(c);


    }

    function getJ(){
        this.echo("inside getJ");
        var jobs = [];
            var names = $('table#requisitionListInterface\\.listRequisition tr[id$=row]');
            __utils__.echo(names);

            for (var i = 0, row; row = names[i]; i++) {
                var $p = $.parseHTML(row.cells[1].innerHTML);
            }

            jobs.push(names);
            return names.length;


    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Message does not appear when called from evaluate method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25135598/message-does-not-appear-when-called-from-evaluate-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably

```
this.echo("inside getJ");
```

is the problem in your case, cause "this" in evaluate function is not the casper object, but probably the Window object.
And since evaluate is executed in sandbox, it does not throw errors out.

Good luck

Comment: you know how to call casperjs click from evaluate function?

Comment: casper.evaluate(function(reason) {
        document.querySelector('#ctl00_Main_ctl00_btnUpdate_IdentityNotes1_txtReasonNotes').value = reason;
        document.querySelector('#ctl00_Main_ctl00_btnUpdate_sb').click();
    }, config.reasonAutorize);

Comment: That last bit is wrong. You can't pass the `casper` object into the page context, because it cannot be serialized.