# Retrieving the checked property of an element in casperjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

At the moment I'm using the casper.evaluate function to do something like this
(Using CoffeeScript)

```
bool = casper.evaluate ->
        document.querySelector('button selector').checked
```

This seems to work fine but I'm wondering if there's a built in casper method that I could use to retrieve the checked property of a checkbox/radio element? I've tried using `getElementAttribute()` but it won't detect 'checked' as an attribute. Also it is not listed in the JSON object retrieved from `getElementInfo()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, CasperJS doesn't provide a function that gives you the checked property of an element, but you can easily create your own:

```
casper.isChecked = function(selector){
    var result = this.evaluate(function(selector){
        var el = document.querySelector(selector);
        return el ? el.checked : null;
    }, selector);
    if (result === null) {
        throw new CasperError("Selector not found");
    }
    return result;
};
```

The reason `getElementAttribute()` and `getElementInfo()` don't provide this is because `checked` is a property of the HTML element and not an attribute. Attributes are usually static and don't change even when the property changes.

Comment: thanks! Quick Javascript quesiton. Why do you have to pass in selector as the second argument in this.evaluate, when you are already making a function that takes in a selector parameter? This resolved an issue that I was having with my other helper functions that were just returning null / empty

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24216243/understanding-evaluate-function-casperjs