# CasperJS Evaluate function not returning Array

Tags: javascript, casperjs

Note, I've already looked  at:

[Understanding the evaluate function in CasperJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24216243/understanding-the-evaluate-function-in-casperjs#24219029)

I am trying to write a simple web-scraper to download all pdf's on my professor's webpage.

Here is my code:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({verbose: true , logLevel: "debug" });
var url = "https://www.cs.rit.edu/~ib/Classes/CSCI264_Fall16-17/assignments.html";
casper.start(url);

var elements; 
try {
    casper.then(function(){
        try {
        // statements
        elements = this.evaluate(function(){ return __utils__.findAll('body ul li a'); });
        console.log("elements: " + elements);
        console.log(this.getCurrentUrl());

        } catch(e) {
            // statements
            console.log(e);
        }   
    });
} catch(e) {

    console.log(e);
}
casper.run();
```

The `elements` array size given back is always zero but when I put

`__utils__.echo(__utils__.findAll('body ul li a').length);`

I get the correct amount of links.

Is this because the evaluate function won't return an array of elements?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use native js methods instead of `__utils__` provided by casperjs, example:

```
elements = this.evaluate(function(){ return document.querySelectorAll('body ul li a'); });
```

I'm not sure why `findAll` didn't work.

Comment: Okay, before I had  "querySelectAll" outside the evaluate function but this is incorrect because then it wouldn't execute within the page document object.  Now it does, thank you.